# Playing audio source from url won't work

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

```
static final String AUDIO_PATH= "http://www.androidbook.com/akc/filestorage/android/documentfiles/3389/play.mp3";



public void playAudio(String url)throws Exception{
    killMediaPlayer();
    sound3=new MediaPlayer();
    sound3.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    sound3.setDataSource(url);
    sound3.setOnPreparedListener(this);
    sound3.prepareAsync();

@Override
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
    mp.start();
}
try {

      playAudio(AUDIO_PATH);

     }
     catch (Exception e){

                      }
```

The method, 'playAudio(Sting url)' won't be invoked, but no error. Please help me find out what the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your exact code (minus the syntax errors) works perfectly for me. However, you may have forgotten to add the following permission to your manifest, as I did:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```